# Any possible explanations for repeated "out-of-the-blue" crashing of Mathematica 12?

Tags: crash, system, system-performance, version-12

This is a further development in this "saga".

After originally asking the question below  (which I will delimit with dashes) a number of months ago, I did get a reponse from Wolfram Technical Support:

"The user report you sent us indicates you were auto-completing a symbol which does not exist in our normal contexts."

This led me to switch my keyboard. (The crashes had seemed to occur "instantaneously" upon pressing certain keys. So instantly that it was hard to know exactly what key had been pressed.)

This change of keyboard seemed to resolve the crashing problem--as I've been running many programs in the intervening few months.

However, a few days ago, it seemed to start recurring--with a "vengeance" (and I have sent the error report to Wolfram Technical Support).

The only possible explanation that occurs to me presently is that a few days ago a security update was installed on my Mac. (A keyboard switch now doesn't seem to work in eliminating the problem.)

I'm so traumatized that I've just been working with Version 11 (for which this never seems to happen), rather than 12. (Needless to say, 12 can run indefinitely [when no further input is made].)

Maybe this will still be considered "off-topic".

---

I had Mathematica 12 installed ten days or so ago (and just now re-installed) on my university computer. Although I do seem to be able to run sustained programs for a day or so, it has also totally unexpectedly crashed on various occasions, even running a few basic lines of commands.

I'd written to support@wolfram.com, but only received as a reply so far:

"In order to better diagnose the issue, please provide more information such as:

-A simple code sample of, say, 10-20 lines that essentially illustrate the issue.

-A screenshot of any windows that show up.

-Any error messages you see when you try to open Mathematica."

Hard to do if everything disappears.

I've been using Mathematica intensively for decades now, and have never encountered a problem remotely similar to this.

I've also been running version 12 at home, and this phenomenon  has not occurred there.

Guess I'll just use Version 11 on campus (for which I've never had such a problem) until this matter resolves itself.

This is my "hardware overview":

Model Name: Mac mini
  Model Identifier: Macmini4,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  2.4 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 3 MB
  Memory:   4 GB
  Bus Speed:    1.07 GHz
  Boot ROM Version: 75.0.0.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 1.65f2
  Serial Number (system):   C07DV0VLDD6L
  Hardware UUID:    58037265-42DA-53A2-8C8C-EF4D37D3AFB6

Any relevance?

In response to the comments, here's the beginning of the Console user report:

Process:               Mathematica [72849]
Path:                  /Applications/Mathematica 3.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica
Identifier:            Mathematica
Version:               12.0.0.6206964 (12.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Mathematica [72849]
User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2019-04-30 12:40:21.397 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G1918)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        52BDE4CB-BD76-9870-077B-D24E45CE6A58

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1F6DA416-FBD3-4B99-9E68-426AE388E0DB

Time Awake Since Boot: 320000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       840 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000078
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x78:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010dc25000-000000010e9b7000 [ 13.6M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Mathematica 3.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.wolfram.Mathematica         0x000000010e12219c 0x10dc25000 + 5231004
1   com.wolfram.Mathematica         0x000000010df48c10 0x10dc25000 + 3292176

Any more needed? Insightful?

Comment: 1) What OS version are you running?  2) Are there any crash logs under "User Reports" in Console.app?

Comment: Agree with @BrettChampion: If you can provide any crash log (for the frontend or kernel) then we can analyze the crash at Wolfram using debug symbol tables we keep for released builds. Also any specific information leading up to the crash is incredibly helpful to narrow down the millions of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the comments/suggestions! The OS is macOS Sierra 10.12.6. Zero messages in my Console. The last crash happened just minutes after re-installation, after entering a few basic commands (no immediate record of them at the moment)--clearly nothing particularly challenging, in the least. How do I find a "crash log" when and if one is available?

Comment: Sorry! I hadn't gone to the "User Reports" in Console.app. There are reports there. Since it's undoubtedly too long for this comment, I'll add the beginning of the report to the question itself

Comment: If you right-click on the entry under "User Reports", you can reveal the actual file in the Finder.  Email that to support.

Comment: I get this random crashing occurring too. I just stopped working for 24+ hour stretches and it seems to be stable enough to do runs of 100x100 of 100x100

Comment: Did you send this to WRI Support?

Comment: Yes, Kuba, I did send (the very lengthy) latest full console user report to support yesterday (I take it that WRI is Wolfram Research...) Interesting comment of CA  Trevillian--why in heaveh's name should "rest periods" be of value? (He should also send his console report to supoort too, it would seem, Good to know I just not being paranoid [ha-ha!])

Comment: Well, maybe it's off-topic, but the submission of the question was very beneficial to my way of thinking. The specific comment of Brett Champion was certainly very helpful. Support hadn't pointed me to the crash logs in User Reports in Console.app--and had just given me a perfunctory reply. The comment of CA Trevillian was certainly informative--indicating that mine was not just a totally isolated event.

Comment: Support wrote me: "The user report you sent us indicates you were auto-completing a symbol which does not exist in our normal contexts". I have since switched my keyboard and the carshing-problem has not recurred.

Comment: new  machine--and new Mathematica 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019) and problem persists (several months later) despite changing of keyboards, setting keyboard options to default..

Comment: Was your previous system 64-bit also? Is your ram ECC, regardless if it is, what kind is it? I never did send a report to support, I just kinda figured I would avoid doing what it is that led to the crashes. But now I have been running some functions in a Remote Desktop that stays on for long times with no real issues, though the kernel isn’t actively being used during that time as I did before when I’d get a crash.

Comment: Thanks--CA Trevillian. I will check these items when next on campus. Also, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251046102?answerId=251979139022#251979139022